# tsql search multiple rows from single input

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My database has a column called tags which is linked to an account number. For example, I could have 5 tags blue, red, green, yellow, pink for one account, red, blue, black for another.

When i do a search, I want to be able to search multiple tags such as blue, red, white and have it return any accounts with any of those tags on it.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I suppose the really best way will be normalize your database first

Comment: The struggle im having is that i need to pass a string (comma separated) and use it in an IN clause but i dont see a way to do that with a variable unless its dynamic sql

Comment: what kind of IN statement do you think of?

Comment: Passing my string of key words and seeing if they exist in the column. As far as I know, WHERE IN(@VAR) wont work.

Comment: so, you need to check each word to be in your column, usually it will look: `COL like '%tag1%' OR COL like '%tag2%'`

Comment: Why not pass a table with one keyword per row as a parameter?

Comment: @HABO How would that look?

Comment: Example _D_ [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187926.aspx#Parameters) shows how to use table-valued parameters. You can `JOIN` the table of keywords with the target table to find the matches. You'll need to check the count of matches for each target row if you want only rows that match _all_ of the specified keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the technique, but you can implement in a different way(for exmaple to have a table-valued function which converts CSV into table with one column):

```
/* Preparaing the test data */
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [UserID] INT
    ,[Tag] VARCHAR(12)
)

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([UserID], [Tag])
VALUES (1, 'red')
      ,(1, 'blue')
      ,(2, 'red')
      ,(2, 'black')
      ,(2, 'green')
      ,(3, 'black')
      ,(3, 'green')
      ,(4, 'yellow')
      ,(5, 'red')
      ,(6, 'black')

/* Setting filter value*/
DECLARE @FiltersValuesInCSV VARCHAR(MAX) = 'red,black'


/* Solution */

DECLARE @XML xml = N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@FiltersValuesInCSV, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>'


;WITH Colors([Color]) AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(250)')))
    FROM @xml.nodes('//r') Tbl(Col)
)
SELECT DISTINCT [UserID]
FROM @DataSource DS
INNER JOIN Colors C
    ON DS.[Tag] = C.[Color]
```